# How to use dhcp6c command to transmit a release message, confirm message, and do stateless dhcp?

Tags: linux, dhcp

I am trying to use the dhcp6c command to transmit a release message but it is unclear how to do that. I did find https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-dhcp6c/ but I was confused about the part where it says "Upon receipt of the SIGHUP or SIGTERM signals, will remove all stateful resources from the system. In the former case the daemon will then reinvoke itself, while it will stop running in the latter case. In either case, will send DHCPv6 Release messages to release resources assigned from servers". It is a Linux device from HPE.

Answer (score 0):

For example, `kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/dhcp6c.pid)` will send a SIGHUP to the currently running `dhcp6c` process, causing it to send DHCPv6 Release message(s) for currently-allocated address(es) and then start over.

Likewise, `kill $(cat /var/run/dhcp6c.pid)` will send a SIGTERM, which will cause `dhcp6c` to send a DHCPv6 Release message (or messages, if appropriate) and then stop.

You cannot use `dhcp6c`send a release message for a IPv6 address that hasn't been already reserved by a running `dhcp6c` process.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of the kill commands you supplied ended up transmitting a release message. The kill -HUP command just makes the device send solicits, no release message prior. Then the second kill command just makes the device send Multicast listener report messages. Is it possible that the commands are completely correct but my device is just not responding in the proper manner with a release message? @telcoM